# How to enumerate USB devices *and* read/write to them?

Tags: c, linux, usb, udev

There is a custom USB device I need to communicate with. There is no particular driver for it. The device doesn't show as `/dev/tty*`.

I [found out](http://www.signal11.us/oss/udev/) how I can use `libudev` to enumerate the USB devices and let's say I manage to get the corresponding `struct udev_device`.

What I can't figure out is how I can `open(2)` the device so I can `write(2)` to and `read(2)` from it.

Is it possible to communicate with a generic USB device, setting baudrate and just read/write? If so, what "file" should I open after I find the device with `libudev`? If not, is writing a kernel-level driver necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`libusb`](http://www.libusb.org/) is an ideal choice. There are also [several examples for such a case as you described](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/examples).

In your case, you just need to:

- Create a default context.
- Request the device list.
- Search for the device with the desired vendor/product ID.
- Open the device, and then communicate via [synchronous](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__syncio.html) or [asynchronous](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__asyncio.html) I/O calls.
- Clean up the requested device list.
- When done, close off the device handle and destroy the context.

This allows you to write a userspace application/library with relative ease. I've used it with microphones, cameras, and DIY hardware (mini assembly line devices I've built) with considerable success. [The devs on the mailing list are also very helpful](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/MailingList), though one or two fellows tend to be somewhat caustic to new members if their posts aren't perfectly written.

Comment: For future readers, libusb opens `/dev/bus/usb/XXX/YYY`.  The `XXX` and `YYY` are the bus and device-on-bus id that you could also see with `lsusb`.